# Simulate long script on page load

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simulate a script that takes a long time to run on page load.

I tried this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(alert("Page Rendered"), 200000);
};
```

But alert message happens instantly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `function()`. [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function(){alert("Page Rendered")}, 200000);
};
```